# Algorithm to minimize total price by using different promotions

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I didn't know what title to use but my problem is as follows:
I have X products to buy - each one costs specified amount.
I have also available 4 types of promotions:

- twoItemPromotion -> can be used for 2 items and discount for **one cheapest** is 22%
- threeItemPromotion -> can be used for 3 items and discount for **one cheapest** is 44%
- fourItemPromotion -> can be used for 4 items and discount for **one cheapest** is 66%
- fiveOrMoreItemPromotion -> can be used for 5 or more items and discount for **one cheapest** is 99.9%

I can split my order of X items however I want so for example if I want to buy 10 items then I can split it to 5 orders that use twoItemPromotion. Or 2 order with threeItemPromotion and 1 with fiveOrMoreItemPromotion.

Here I modeled some value objects to represent items and promotions:

```
fun main() {
    val itemA = Item(name = "A", price = 1000)
    val itemB = Item(name = "B", price = 1500)
    val itemC = Item(name = "C", price = 2000)
    val itemD = Item(name = "D", price = 1200)
    val itemE = Item(name = "E", price = 1600)
    val itemF = Item(name = "F", price = 1300)
    val itemG = Item(name = "G", price = 2400)
    val itemH = Item(name = "H", price = 800)
    val itemJ = Item(name = "J", price = 1400)
    val itemK = Item(name = "K", price = 1200)

    val itemListToBuy = listOf(itemA, itemB, itemC, itemD, itemE, itemF, itemG, itemH, itemJ, itemK)

    val twoItemPromotion = Promotion(numberOfItems = 2, discountForCheapest = 0.22)
    val threeItemPromotion = Promotion(numberOfItems = 3, discountForCheapest = 0.44)
    val fourItemPromotion = Promotion(numberOfItems = 4, discountForCheapest = 0.66)
    val fiveOrMoreItemPromotion = Promotion(numberOfItems = 5, discountForCheapest = 0.9999)


}

data class Item(val name: String, val price: Int)

data class Promotion(val numberOfItems: Int, val discountForCheapest: Double)
```

How would you go about retrieving the best combination of which products to use with which promotion and how much it would save? I'm curious what's the efficient way to calculate the best composition if I wanted to use this for example for 500 items or so.

EDIT: 
To clarify how the promotion works:
If I place order with those 3 items:

```
val itemA = Item(name = "A", price = 1000)
val itemB = Item(name = "B", price = 1500)
val itemC = Item(name = "C", price = 2000)
```

Then without promotion it would cost `1000 + 1500 + 2000 = 4500`.
But when taking into account **threeItemPromotion** the cheapest one - **itemA** - has his price reduced by **44%** => **itemA** costs: `1000 * (1-0.44) = 556` and the rest of the items - **itemB** and **itemC** - have unnaffected price meaning that together they cost `556 (cheapest item with discount) + 1500 + 2000 = 4056`

EDIT 2:
Right now I have this:

```
    fun main() {
    val itemA = Item(name = "A", price = 1000)
    val itemB = Item(name = "B", price = 1500)
    val itemC = Item(name = "C", price = 2000)
    val itemD = Item(name = "D", price = 1200)
    val itemE = Item(name = "E", price = 1600)
    val itemF = Item(name = "F", price = 1300)
    val itemG = Item(name = "G", price = 2400)
    val itemH = Item(name = "H", price = 800)
    val itemJ = Item(name = "J", price = 1400)
    val itemK = Item(name = "K", price = 1200)

    val itemList = listOf(itemA, itemB, itemC, itemD, itemE, itemF, itemG, itemH, itemJ, itemK)

    val sorted = itemList.sortedBy { it.price }

    val bestResult = mutableListOf(Result(0.0, 0))

    for (i in 0 until sorted.size) {
        var best = Result(
            cost = (sorted.get(i).price) + bestResult.get(i).cost,
            groupSize = 1
        )
        for (s in 2..5) {
            val candidate = Result(cost = getPrice(i - s, sorted), groupSize = s)
            if (candidate.cost < best.cost) {
                best = candidate
            }
        }
        bestResult.add(best)
    }

    bestResult.forEach { println(it) }
}



  fun getPrice(numberOfItems: Int, list: List<Item>): Double {
    val found = mutableListOf<Int?>()
    for(i in 0 until numberOfItems) {
        found.add(list.getOrNull(i)?.price)
    }
    val filterNotNull = found.filterNotNull()
    return when(numberOfItems) {
        2 -> (filterNotNull.get(0) * 0.78 + filterNotNull.get(1))
        3 -> (filterNotNull.get(0) * 0.56 + filterNotNull.get(1) + filterNotNull.get(2))
        4 -> (filterNotNull.get(0) * 0.34 + filterNotNull.get(1) + filterNotNull.get(2) + filterNotNull.get(3))
        5 -> (1.0 + filterNotNull.get(1) + filterNotNull.get(2) + filterNotNull.get(3) + filterNotNull.get(4))
        else -> 1000000000.0
    }
}
data class Item(val name: String, val price: Int)

data class Result(val cost: Double, val groupSize: Int)
```

But it's not calculating the prices correctly - I assume I have error in getPrice() method. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem. what do you mean by "one cheapest"? Say I'm buying two, the third one i can buy with 22% less? or something else? Sorry - I don't get it.

Comment: Added edit with example how it actually works

Comment: Okay, so you are looking for 500 items, since items are different priced, the result will vary with input, though 500 is fixed. You need to specify exactly how many A, B, C, ... are present in the order.

Comment: The keywords to search on are "dynamic programming" and "partition problem".   You need to consider a variety of options; you can reduce the search tree with some algebraic limits (for strict dominance), and let your DP backtracking identify the best solution.  This is a matter of technique application, more than a particular algorithm.

Comment: Your `getPrice` has two problems that come to mind.  The first is that you have to get the price for a range of the list with a start and and end.  The second is that you need bounds checks to not run off of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an observation.  Sort your items from cheapest to most expensive.

Now suppose that I have a grouping that is claimed to be optimal.  Look at the group that has the very cheapest item.  If the rest of the group is not the next cheapest items, I can trade out which items are in the group until it is without making it worse.  And then I can do the same with the next.

The result is that you there is a best arrangement where each group is contiguous in that list.  This observation greatly reduces your combinatorial explosion of possibilities to look at.

And now it is a great candidate for dynamic programming as follows.

```
item_infos = ((i.price, i.name, i) for i in item_list_to_buy)
item_infos = sorted(item_infos)
best_result = [{cost: 0, group_size: 0}]
for i in range(len(item_infos)):
    best = {cost: item_infos[i][0] + best_result[i].cost, group_size: 1}
    for s in [2, 3, 4, 5]:
        candidate = do calculation of group of size s ending here
        if candidate.cost < best.cost:
            best = candidate
    best_result.append(best)
```

In your case your `item_infos` would wind up being:

```
[
    (800, 'H', itemH)
  , (1000, 'A', itemA)
  , (1200, 'D', itemD)
  , (1200, 'K', itemK)
  , (1300, 'F', itemF)
  , (1400, 'J', itemJ)
  , (1500, 'B', itemB)
  , (1600, 'E', itemE)
  , (2000, 'C', itemC)
  , (2400, 'G', itemG)
]
```

And then your `best_result` would be (modulo mistakes from doing this by hand)

```
[
    {cost: 0, group_size: 0}
  , {cost: 800, group_size: 1}
  , {cost: 1980, group_size: 2}
  , {cost: 2648, group_size: 3}
  , {cost: 3760, group_size: 3}
  , {cost: 4700.8, group_size: 5}
  , {cost: 5901, group_size: 5}
  , {cost: 7256, group_size: 4}
  , {cost: 8449.2, group_size: 5}
  , {cost: 10261.3, group_size: 5}
  , {cost: 12202.2, group_size: 5}
]
```

And now we read it off.

We want the last 5 as a group `[J, B, E, C, G]`.  Which lands us at `{cost: 4700.8, group_size: 5}` so we want the next to last 5 as a group `[H, A, K, D, F]`.

This algorithm runs in linear time, so finding an optimal answer for 500 items should be easy.

NOTE: If your promos start to be specific groups of items that go together, this problem goes from easy to potentially NP complete...

Comment: I'm having trouble with calculating current price for candidate... I added a snippet in EDIT 2 section - maybe you can point where I have a mistake so the prices aren't calculated properly